# Contraint two generic type parameters to have a parent child relationship

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to write a cast operator to cast a generic type to another with a parent type parameter
For example

```
public static implicit operator Result<ParentT, ErrorT>.Ok(Result<ChildT, ErrorT>.Ok val) => new Result<ParentT, ErrorT>.Ok(val);
```

Can I specify a constraint that `ChildT` can be cast, implicitly or explicitly, into `ParentT`?
The `Result` type in the above example is defined below

```
public abstract record Result<T, ErrorT>
{
    public sealed record Ok(T Value) : Result<T, ErrorT>;
    public sealed record Error(ErrorT ErrorValue) : Result<T, ErrorT>;
}
```

Comment: You cannot describe allowed conversion as part of the type declaration. You can provide type constraints for the generic types, probably as an interface.

Comment: As an aside, the expected naming convention would be `TParent`, `TError`, `TChild`